# Setting Android Character Width

Tags: android, text, canvas

You can control the height of a text character, drawn into the canvas, with setTextSize().  For example, if you want text of height 8 pixels, you would write:

```
mPaint.setTextSize(8);
```

This works fairly well.  However, I cannot seem to find a way to set the width.  Hence a 8x12 pixel character looks exactly the same as an 12x12 character.  I am using monospace font and want to carefully control the size of each character in a canvas.

Any ideas on how to set character width in pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the vertical height of the text is considered the text's "size", while the horizontal width is considered the "scale". For example, if you are drawing text onto a canvas using a Paint, the Paint has methods called [getTextScaleX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextScaleX%28%29) and [setTextScaleX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setTextScaleX%28float%29) which you can use to:

> Get [and set] the paint's horizontal scale factor for text.

Depending on how you are using the canvas these may be the methods you want to use - most other methods for text deal with horizontal text spacing rather than modifying the size of the actual characters themselves.

Comment: Thank you, setTextScaleX() fixed it.  Next problem is that the text is not monospacing correctly.  I would hate to have to render each character one at a time.  Still have to work on that problem...

Comment: You're using the Droid Mono font I assume? It's possible that the spacing/kerning doesn't play nice when you alter the horizontal text scale. In what way, exactly, is it "not monospacing correctly?"

Comment: P.s. consider 'accepting' my answer (by clicking the checkmark outline) if it helped you - and you might also consider going back to your old questions and accepting answers for some of them too. This is generally good to do so future viewers know which solution worked for you (if they have the same problem).

Comment: Yes, I am using the droid Mono.  Suppose the font is 8wx12h pixels.  I can get a single character to fit inside this box and look good.  But when I give my drawing algorithm a longer string (which just calls canvas.drawText()), the characters don't seem to be monospaced.  The solution would be a loop that calls drawText for each single character, and manually advancing the "x" position by 8.  But I'd rather get Android to do it.  ;)

Comment: You may be able to get some information from the Paint's `getTextWidths` or `getFontSpacing` functions, but I'm not sure how much it will tell you. It's hard to guess where the problem is - either the Canvas not following the Paint's settings correctly or  the `setTextScaleX` not playing nice with Droid Mono / not handling spacing properly. It will probably require some experimentation to figure out.

Comment: I have a similar case print out that is paint on canvas (standard printout on paper/PDF example code works else just fine). I want a narrow font in special cases (long numbers) and problems with paint.setTextScaleX, any scale but 1.0f makes just a blur printout.
In textview.setTextScaleX works fine on the screen, get nice narrow font and more space for a huge number, but on paper printouts not. Anyone got an idea what could be the fuzz, or am I trying a Munchausen?